# What do the X%'s next to the Dungeon Room's Level mean?

Tags: dungeonmaker

In DungeonMaker, what do the %'s next to the various traps and battle rooms mean? I'm guessing it is an experience marker for the next level but I haven't found much documentation on the game.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Percentage to next level.

[According to Reddit,](https://www.reddit.com/r/DungeonMaker/comments/8wk431/what_does_that_percentage_mean/) it's the percentage of XP remaining until the item's next level.

[image]